# Ending a QDrag Prematurely

Tags: qt, pyqt, qt5, pyqt5

I want my application to terminate all drag and drops in a `dragLeaveEvent`, without the user releasing the mouse button.

The problem is that the loop suspends all events that could cancel a `QDrag` while it is happening, even though the documentation states:

> "On Linux and Mac OS X, the drag and drop operation can take some
>   time, but this function does not block the event loop. Other events
>   are still delivered to the application while the operation is
>   performed. On Windows, the Qt event loop is blocked during the
>   operation. However, QDrag.exec() on Windows causes processEvents() to
>   be called frequently to keep the GUI responsive. If any loops or
>   operations are called while a drag operation is active, it will block
>   the drag operation."

Because of this, I cannot call events which would end the drag.

So far, I've tried what is suggested [here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/32237/ending-qdrag-prematurely/), as seen in the code. I'm using PyQt5, but if a solution works in Qt it should work in PyQt.

Edit: I'm a little scared to delete the drag, as the scene does not own it. I suppose I could set it up to own it though, but as was posted [here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/32237/ending-qdrag-prematurely/2) it should not work.

Edit2: Added code with my non-working attempts to fix it. I'd really like to solve this issue without having to make my own drag-drop framework. Also trimmed post.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QMainWindow, QApplication,
    QGraphicsView, QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsWidget, QGraphicsRectItem)
from PyQt5.QtCore import (QMimeData, Qt, QByteArray, QCoreApplication,
    QEvent, QPoint)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QBrush, QColor, QDrag, QPen, QMouseEvent


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.scene = CustomScene()
        self.view = QGraphicsView(self.scene, self)
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 600, 600)
        self.view.setGeometry(0, 0, 500, 500)
        self.show()


class CustomScene(QGraphicsScene):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.customWidgets = []
        for i in range(5):
            newItem = CustomDragWidget()
            self.addItem(newItem)
            self.customWidgets.append(newItem)
            newItem.setGeometry(i * 50, i * 50, 50, 50)

    def dragLeaveEvent(self, event):
        # Work your magic here. I've tried the following:
        # 1)
        self.customWidgets[0].dropEvent(event)
        # 2)
        self.dropEvent(event)
        # 3)
        eve = QMouseEvent(QEvent.MouseButtonRelease, QPoint(0, 0), Qt.LeftButton, Qt.LeftButton, Qt.NoModifier)
        QCoreApplication.sendEvent(self.views()[0], eve)
        QCoreApplication.processEvents()
        # 4)
        eve = QMouseEvent(QEvent.MouseButtonRelease, QPoint(0, 0), Qt.LeftButton, Qt.LeftButton, Qt.NoModifier)
        QCoreApplication.sendEvent(self.customWidgets[0], eve)
        QCoreApplication.processEvents()

    def dropEvent(self, QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent):
        # a dummy dropevent that tries to stop the drop, but doesnt work
        QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent.accept()

class CustomDragWidget(QGraphicsWidget):
    def __init__(self,):
        super().__init__()
        self.squareItem = QGraphicsRectItem()
        self.squareItem.setBrush(QBrush(QColor(Qt.blue)))
        self.squareItem.setPen(QPen(QColor(Qt.black), 2))
        self.squareItem.setRect(0, 0, 50, 50)
        self.squareItem.setParentItem(self)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        mime = QMimeData()
        itemData = QByteArray()
        mime.setData('application/x-dnditemdata', itemData)
        drag = QDrag(self)
        drag.setMimeData(mime)
        drag.exec(Qt.MoveAction)

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        event.accept()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MainWindow()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Can you provide a small, self-contained example that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Sure! I'm editing the post now.

Comment: Done editing, and the code is now copy-pastable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little bit hackish, but it seems to work (on Linux, anyway):

```
    def dragLeaveEvent(self, event):
        QCoreApplication.postEvent(self,
            QKeyEvent(QEvent.KeyPress, Qt.Key_Escape, Qt.NoModifier))
```

Comment: It's not working over here in the Windows 10 world. The ForbiddenCursor is still showing :(

Comment: @TheSmartWon. Does pressing the real escape key cancel a drag on Windows? Or is there some other way to cancel a drag via the keyboard on Windows?

Comment: The escape key does indeed word on Windows. It just seems that the event, wherever it is received, is still not puttering down the chain to QDrop. Perhaps it is a Windows only problem.

Comment: @TheSmartWon. Yeah, my gut feeling is that you are basically screwed on Windows. It just blocks everything. It seems that Qt uses the platform drag and drop system on Windows, so there is no way to interrupt it. Possibly you could use the WinAPIs to work around this, but I have no idea how.

Comment: Sounds about right. Thanks for your help, I'll write my own drag and drop code from the other mouseEvents. Usually that type of pain isn't worth it.